# Invalid object name 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes' and 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes'

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, cdc

I want to capture the net changes in the CDC table through lookup activity in azure data factory in SQL Server.

I followed this tutorial:
[Incrementally load data from Azure SQL Managed Instance to Azure Storage using change data capture (CDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal)

I am able to run both `fn_cdc_get_min_lsn` and `fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn` and got the respective values. But when running

```
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_CUST');
SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or 
equal', GETDATE());
SELECT count(1) changecount FROM 
cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_CUST(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all')
```

I am encountering the error.

[image]

[image]

> A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object name 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_CUST'.'Invalid object name 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_CUST'., SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,State=1,

Sample CDC table [image]

Comment: Could you please provide your sample table?

Comment: This is the third time this question has been asked, by the third different user! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And please don't use images... use formatted text.

Comment: Instead of deleting your question and re-asking it (as another user no less), improve your original question. There is an [edit] option.

Comment: Sorry @DaleK, i was having some problems.

Comment: added images @Bhavani

Comment: @Boris please do not use images - use formatted text!

Comment: @Boris are you having cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_CUST table in your database

Comment: @Bhavani I do not have the permission to check that. i can only use it through linked service. I do have dbo.CUST and cdc.dbo_CUST_CT

Comment: create ad dataset with the linked service and click on select table drop down, then you will be able to check the tables in the database

Comment: @Bhavani no, the database doesn't contain the table.

Comment: Have you [enabled change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal#create-a-data-source-table-in-azure-sql-database) on the table before inserting data into table. I have followed the document which you provided I am not getting any error.

Comment: Once check your database in linked service, if you select the wrong database, you may the error.

Comment: @Bhavani i checked that the sql server has not configured the net_changes or all_changes. Any other ways to get the net_change value using CDC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the correct database in the linked service as shown below:

[image]

Otherwise, you may encounter the error shown below:

```
A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object name 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_customers'.'Invalid object name 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_customers'., SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,State=1,
```

Additionally, ensure that you have [enabled change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal#create-a-data-source-table-in-azure-sql-database) on the table before inserting data into it using the script below:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db 

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema = 'dbo',
@source_name = 'CUST', 
@role_name = NULL,
@supports_net_changes = 1
```

By following the above steps, you will be able to obtain the output of the lookup activity as shown below:

[image]